# Is there a "closed form" for the taylor series of $\sqrt{1+f[x]}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, power-series

I would like a simple, computationally viable expansion in $x$ of $\sqrt{1+f[x]}$. If we taylor expand $f[x] $ itself inside the square root to first couple of orders, and expand the square root for small x we have for example,

$\sqrt{1+f[0]+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\partial^{n}_xf[x]|_{x=0}}{n!}x^n}$= $\frac{x f'(0)}{2 \sqrt{f(0)+1}}+\frac{x^2 \left(2 f(0) f''(0)+2 f''(0)-f'(0)^2\right)}{8 (f(0)+1)^{3/2}}+\sqrt{f(0)+1}$.

Does this type of expression has a closed form? I suspect one can rewrite this as exp of log and then use the Faa di Bruno formula for the exponential, but this seems to require expanding $\log{\left(1+f[0]+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\partial^{n}_xf[x]|_{x=0}x^n\right)}$, which also seems complicated.

Comment: How did you get that expression on the RHS?  What is $R'(0)$?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, should be f. I did a series expansion in x around zero, for example on mathematica

Comment: So you are doing *two* series expansions?  Why not directly perform a Taylor expansion on $\sqrt{1+f(x)}$ and use Faa di Bruno to compute its $n$th derivative?

Comment: Define $g(x)=1+f(x)$ and use https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_power_series#Operations_on_formal_power_series

Comment: @Golden_Ratio how would you do that in a computationally viable way (ie to high orders in x)? It seems to me I would have to use $\log(1+f(x))$ expansions to use the Faa di Bruno formula and this involves iterated sums which gets slow after a few orders.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici thank you, that's a useful formula! It would be ideal if there was a closed form for the c's since I'm worried that having to solve for those recursively will also slow down the procedure at higher orders, but I will give that a try

Comment: @Noam. Avoid dreaming too much ! (no totally a joke).But this is a closed form.

Comment: @Noam I meant define $h(x):=g(f(x))$ where $g(x):=\sqrt{1+x}$.  You want a Taylor series of $h$ right? You can use Faa di Bruno to write the $n$th derivative of $h$.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici the formula is only valid for $a_0$ not equal to zero and unless I'm missing something your idea will only work if I take $f(x)$ to start at order x (so combining $f(0)$ with the constant 1)

Comment: @Golden_Ratio If you can be more explicit on how you would do this would be great. If you mean the first formula quoted in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fa%C3%A0_di_Bruno%27s_formula then the iterated sums take too long once you go above order $x^8$ so that is not computationally viable for me. If you mean something else then an explicit computation to show me what you mean would be helpful :)

Comment: @Golden_Ratio although I'm seeing now that there is a formula there explicitly given with the Bell polynomials- did you mean this?

Comment: You need that $1+f(0) >0$ to have a series in $x$. If $1+f(0)=0$ you have a series in powers of $\sqrt(x)$.

Comment: @Golden_Ratio thank you! this method is currently working out as the fastest indeed

Comment: @Noam Great, glad it worked out!